# Gson parse to subclass that overrides variable

Tags: java, json, class, gson, pojo

I want to make some response POJO classes which I will receive from my webserver.

My webserver will always return a json in this structure:

```
{
    'data':Object or array or null,
    'status':Integer,
    'message':String or null
}
```

This is the BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse {
    private Object data;
    private int status;
    private String message;

    public Object getData() { return this.data; }
    public int getStatus() { return this.status; }
    public String getMessage() { return this.message; }
}
```

Then I have one 'real' response class:

```
public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse {
    private UserData data;

    @Override
    public UserData getData() { return data; }
}
```

`UserData` is another class that looks exactly like these but with different variable names (id and name).

I try to parse the response like this:

```
try {
    LoginResponse json = gson.fromJson(jsonString, LoginResponse.class);
    Log.i(PF.TAG, "ID: " + json.getData().getName());
}
```

But it throws an exception on fromJson() saying:

> LoginResponse declares multiple JSON fields named data

How can I fix this and still have the data variable in `BaseResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic types.

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {

    private T data;
    private int status;
    private String message;

    public T getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public int getStatus(){
        return this.status;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

An example response type:

```
public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse<UserData>{

}
```

then you can use:

```
LoginResponse json = gson.fromJson(jsonString, LoginResponse.class);
Log.i(PF.TAG, "ID: " + json.getData().getName());
```

With this method T can be any object you wish.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that x) Now I don't even need the subclasses... Thanks!